# Batch file: GOTO in a FOR loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, goto

I have a batch file with a FOR loop. In the loop I must wait for a process to end, for which I used IF and GOTO. The problem is the GOTO is breaking the loop. I tried to find other solutions but I didn't find anything. How can it be done?

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (file.txt) do (
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
:check
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq prog.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "prog.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (goto check)
)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Inside the loop, you could use a `call` to a subroutine, there are `goto`s allowed.
The loop will not be broken by a `call` to a subroutine.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (file.txt) do (
  bla bla bla
  bla bla bla
  call :check
)
exit /b

:check
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq prog.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "prog.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (goto check)
exit /b
```