# Windows batch goto inside FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, goto

I have a Windows batch file to read a file, get some info from it, like machine IP, and then print some registry values for that machine, something like this:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,* delims=;" %%a in ('findstr /R "^" z:\csp\levantamento\levantamentoNOVO.csv') do (

set /A "HOME=0"

:cicle
echo HOME%HOME%
echo \\%%c\HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME%HOME%

reg query \\%%c\HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME%HOME% /v ORACLE_HOME

if %HOME% leq 3 (
    set /A "HOME+=1"
    goto cicle
) else (
    echo.
)

echo Conenction to %%a deleted
)
```

and my output is this:

```
HOME0
\\10.13.3.27\HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME0
    ORACLE_HOME    REG_EXPAND_SZ    d:\oracle\806

HOME1
\\%c\HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME1
ERROR: The network path was not found.
HOME2
\\%c\HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME2
ERROR: The network path was not found.
HOME3
\\%c\HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME3
ERROR: The network path was not found.
HOME4
\\%c\HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME4
ERROR: The network path was not found.


Conenction to %a deleted
```

When I do a *goto cicle*, it appear that the FOR loop doesn't know anymore hat the %%c and %%c are. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you use a `goto` command inside a `for` loop, the `for` is canceled, there are no more iterations and the `for` replaceable parameters/variables go out of scope.

Comment: So, is there a way to do what I'm trying to?

Comment: Replace your inner loop with a `for /l %%x in (0 1 3) do ....` command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch file: GOTO in a FOR loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177419/batch-file-goto-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,* delims=;" %%a in ('findstr /R "^" z:\csp\levantamento\levantamentoNOVO.csv') do (

 set /A HOME=0
 call :cicle "%%a" "%%c"
)

:: what-to-do-after-for goes in here

goto :eof

:cicle
echo HOME%HOME%
echo \\%~2\HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME%HOME%

reg query \\%~2\HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME%HOME% /v ORACLE_HOME

if %HOME% leq 3 (
    set /A HOME+=1
    goto cicle
)
echo.

echo Connection to %~1 deleted
goto :eof
```

Note that now there is a subroutine called `cicle` which is supplied with parameters `"%%a"` and `"%%c"` Within the `cicle` routine, what was `%%a` becomes `%~1` (the first parameter, minus the quotes) and what was `%%c` becomes `%~2` (the second parameter, minus the quotes).

The quotes are only there in case the parameter being passed contains separator characters, which is unlikely in your current case.

see `call /?` from the prompt for docco.

Note also that `set "var=variable"` is used in string assignments to ensure unwanted trailing spaces are not included in the value assigned. The `set /a` syntax does not suffer from this problem, so the rabbit's ears are not necessary.

Comment: MC ND answer was on the spot! the best way is to do a for /l loop