# Extract first 4-digit number

Tags: batch-file

I can't manage to find a solution, I have some .jpg files in a folder, I want to extract the first 4-digits number in the filename. For exemple: photo.20.2023-beach.jpg I would like to extract 2023. Everything I do gets me 2020... I know very little of batch and work with chatgpt mostly to get the basics of my codes, I usually get to where I want, but here I'm stuck.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Set the current directory
set "directory=%cd%"

rem Iterate through all .jpg files in the directory
for %%F in ("%directory%\*.jpg") do (
    rem Extract the first four-digit number from the filename
    set "filename=%%~nF"
    set "digits="
    
    rem Loop through each character in the filename
    for /l %%I in (0, 1, 255) do (
        set "char=!filename:~%%I,1!"

        rem Check if the character is a digit
        if "!char!" geq "0" if "!char!" leq "9" (
            set "digits=!digits!!char!"

            rem Check if four consecutive digits are found
            if defined digits (
                set "firstDigit=!digits:~0,1!"
                set "fourthDigit=!digits:~3,1!"
                if defined fourthDigit (
                    if !firstDigit! neq "0" (
                        echo File: %%F, First four-digit number: !digits!
                        goto :found_digits
                    ) else (
                        set "digits=!fourthDigit!"
                    )
                )
            )
        ) else (
            set "digits="
        )
    )

    rem Check if digits were found
    :found_digits
    if not defined digits (
        echo File: %%F, No four-digit number found
    )
)
```

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting the first sequence of four digits? or the first sequence of only four digits? Example: `IMG_12.12345_A-5432.JPG`, the first sequence of four digits is `1234`, but the first sequence of only four digits is `5432`.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help, it would be the first sequence of only four digits, 5432 in your exemple

Comment: You cannot `goto` a `:Label` within a parenthesised block since `goto` breaks the block context (perhaps try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177419) instead)…

Comment: Another thing: in `if "!char!" geq "0" if "!char!" leq "9" ( … ) else …`, the `else` refers to `if "!char!" leq "9"`, so you lack one `else`, I guess; you maybe should write `if "!char!" geq "0" ( if "!char!" leq "9" ( … ) else ( set "digits=" )) else ( set "digits=" )` (the additional pair of `(` `)` is mandatory)…

Answer (score 2):

The AI "solution" is like slamming the tree against the axe. Split the string into substrings (be sure to include all possible delimiters) and check each substring for "exactly 4 digits" (I guess that's what you want, if not, please be more precise)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

break>photo.20.2023-beach.jpg
break>photo.55-2020_sea.jpg
break>1234-55.33-test.jpg
break>no-match.jpg
break>IMG_12.12345_A-5432.JPG

for /f "delims=" %%Y in ('dir /b /a-d *.jpg') do (
  for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=._-" %%A in ("%%Y") do (
    rem echo %%A %%B %%C %%D %%E %%F %%G
    set "four="
    for %%Z in (%%A %%B %%C %%D %%E %%F %%G) do (
      echo %%Z|findstr /x "[01234656789][01234656789][01234656789][01234656789]" >nul && if not defined four set "four=%%Z"
    )
    if defined four (
      echo %%Y  --- !four!
    ) else (
      echo %%Y  --- no match
    )
  )
)
```

Output:

```
1234-55.33-test-9876.jpg  --- 1234
IMG_12.12345_A-5432.JPG  --- 5432
no-match.jpg  --- no match
photo.20.2023-beach.jpg  --- 2023
photo.55-2020_sea.jpg  --- 2020
```

Comment: You're solution worked for my case, thank you! Even though I went and use a regex in the end to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: The `findstr` in my answer is the best of REGEX that batch/cmd is able to offer in this case. If you can use (the help of) more modern languages (like PowerShell), your options are way better of course - and you definitively should use them when possible. Just remember, calling Powershell within cmd decreases the speed considerably (if that's a concern to take care of). A pure PowerShell solution would be the optimal solution.

Comment: Thank, as I've said, i've working with an AI... I've tried doing it with powershell but it struggled even more than with batch ^^ And speed is not an issue, I'll never batch a tons of file at the time. But even though I'm working with ai, I'm trying to learn as much as I can, so it's always nice to see how it would work with batch!

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Set the current directory
set "directory=m:\graphics"

rem Iterate through all .jpg files in the directory
for %%e in ("%directory%\*.jpg") do (
 rem Extract the first four-digit number from the filename
 set "filename=%%~ne"
 set "digits="
 SET /a dcount=0
 FOR /L %%y IN (1,1,500) DO IF !dcount! lss 4 IF DEFINED filename (
  SET "isdigit="
  IF "!filename:~0,1!" geq "0" IF "!filename:~0,1!" leq "9" SET "isdigit=Y"
  IF DEFINED isdigit (
   SET /a dcount+=1
   SET "digits=!digits!!filename:~0,1!"
  ) ELSE (
   set "digits="
   SET /a dcount=0
  )
  SET "filename=!filename:~1!"
 )
 IF NOT !dcount!==4 SET "digits=????"
 IF NOT DEFINED digits SET "digits=????"
 ECHO !digits! %%~ne
)
GOTO :EOF
```

[`M:\graphics` is my directory of believe it or not, graphics files]

This routine simply examines the first character of the filename and sets a flag depending on digit/non-digit.

Then, count the digits and accumulate the sequence but reset the count and sequence if a non-digit appears.

Then lop off the first character of the filename.

Continue until there are no more characters in the filename or we find 4 consecutive digits.

Note that the original code had no hope of working since it included a label `:found_digits` within a `code block` (parenthesised sequence of commands) and labels re not allowed within a code block.

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to have accepted the use of PowerShell for solutions, perhaps this example would perform the task as laid out in your question, i.e. to 'extract' each first sequence of exactly four digits in your filenames.

```bash
@(For /F %%G In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command
 "Get-ChildItem '.\*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.jpg' -File"
 " | ForEach-Object {([RegEx]'\D(\d{4})\D').Match($_).Groups[1].Value}"'
) Do @Echo %%G) & Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is interesting! **`;)`** Of course, it is more interesting if you do *not* use a regexp to solve it and yet keep the code simple and small... This is my attempt:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in ( photo.20.2023-beach.jpg photo.55-2020_sea.jpg 1234-55.33-test.jpg
             no-match.jpg IMG_12.12345_A-5432.JPG IMG_12.1234_A-5432.JPG ) do rem/> %%a


for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
   for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=._-" %%A in ("%%a") do (
      set "four="
      for %%b in (%%A %%B %%C %%D %%E %%F) do (
         set /A "num=%%b" 2> NUL
         if !num! gtr 999 if !num!!four! leq 9999 set "four=!num!"
      )
      if defined four (
         echo %%a  --- !four!
      ) else (
         echo %%a  --- no match
      )
   )
)
```

Output:

```
1234-55.33-test.jpg  --- 1234
IMG_12.12345_A-5432.JPG  --- 5432
IMG_12.1234_A-5432.JPG  --- 1234
no-match.jpg  --- no match
photo.20.2023-beach.jpg  --- 2023
photo.55-2020_sea.jpg  --- 2020
```

Comment: Surely this assumes that the delimiters, and I suppose, the actual maximum number of tokens, are known in advance. BTW, your solution would fail to identify `5432` in the following filename: ```IMG_12.0X270F_A-5432.JPG```.

Comment: @Compo: Of course! It will also fail with any name that include an octal or hexadecimal number. However, the important point is if this solution fulfills the OP's requirements...

Comment: TBF Aacini, my assumption is that [the answer posted by the OP themself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77856186), does that. _(Although that is seemingly only a part answer, and does not technically perform the task laid out in the actual question they posed)_. My main reason for commenting is that a solution which makes so many assumptions with regards filenames and their characters, seems a poor choice when a regex can be more specific and succinct. After all there are literally thousands of filenames which will fail with your code above, however unlikely we may expect them to occur.

Answer (score -1):

Yet another approach.

Delayed expansion is toggled on / off each loop after assignment of the filename to preserve any `!` characters present

Gets the string length of each filename

walks the string length using substring of the filename at index,4

uses `delims=0123456789` to modify variables that flag if the current substring is entirely numerical or not

Additional Tests of each character at an offset of +-1 to the index,4 being tested rule out instances of integers containing 5 or more digits.

```
@Echo off

Call:DefMacro


For /f "delims=" %%T in ('Dir /B %CD%\*.JPG')Do (
    Set "FileName=%%T"
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    %$strLen% $Len FileName
    Set "First="
    For /l %%i in (0 1 !$Len!)Do If not defined First (
        Set /a "offset[1]=%%i-1","offset[2]=%%i+4"
        Set "False="
        For /F "Delims=0123456789" %%G in ("!FileName:~%%i,4!")Do (
            Set "False=1"
        )
        If not Defined False (
            If not %%i EQU 0 Set "false=1"
            For /f "tokens=1,2" %%O in ("!offset[1]! !Offset[2]!")Do (
                If %%i GTR 0 For /F "Delims=0123456789" %%G in ("!FileName:~%%O,1!")Do Set "false="
                If not defined false For /F "Delims=0123456789" %%G in ("!FileName:~%%P,1!")Do (
                    Set "First=!FileName:~%%i,4!"
                    Echo(!FileName! - !First!
    )   )   )   )
    If "!First!" == "" REM No match !Filename!
    Endlocal
)
Pause
Goto:Eof

:DefMacro
REM StrLen source: https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10983
(set ^"$\n=^^^
%= This creates an escaped Line Feed - DO NOT ALTER =%
)

set $strLen=for %%# in (1 2) do if %%#==2 ( %$\n%
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%1 in ("!argv!") do ( %$\n%
%=      *** remove the local variable "argv" =% %$\n%
    endlocal %$\n%
%=      *** copy content to temporary variable, the carets are for extended length, up to 8191chars =% %$\n%
    (set^^ s=!%%~2!) %$\n%
    if defined s ( %$\n%
        set "len=1" %$\n%
        for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do ( %$\n%
          if "!s:~%%P,1!" neq "" ( %$\n%
            set /a "len+=%%P" %$\n%
            set "s=!s:~%%P!" %$\n%
          ) %$\n%
        ) %$\n%
    ) ELSE set "len=0" %$\n%
    for %%V in (!len!) do endlocal ^& set "%%~1=%%V" %$\n%
  ) %$\n%
) else setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion ^& setlocal ^& set argv=,
Exit /b 0
```

Answer (score -1):

I finally found something that works for me, and in addition to find the first sequence of four digit, I add parenthesis around it. As follow

```
for /f "delims=" %%P in ('powershell -command "& { [regex]::Replace('!filename!', '\b(\d{4})\b', '($1)') }"') do (
        set "filename=%%P"
```

Comment: This solution replaces all instances of 4 digit integers, not just the first instance. Additionally, if the filename is assigned during a for loop whilst delayed expansion is enabled, filenames containing `!` may provide false matches.

Comment: I have multiple instances of 4 digits, it just grabs the first in my case, so for that, I'd say it works. For filenames containing exclamation point though, you might be right, but that will never be the case for so that's ok for me -- even if it might not be the best solution!

Comment: @T3RR0R So i've tried it just by curiosity, and you're right it doesn't handle '!'. What would I need to change if I want to make this better and handle any special character?

Comment: As per the explanation in my answer, Delayed expansion should be disabled at the time `Filename` is defined, and enabled when expanding the variable.